# how to place answers to random options?

Tags: android

Hello guys I am a newbie in this whole android world.I started with my trivia application but I cannot figure something here how do I randomize the options that the user is gonna choose I mean I will be giving 4 options but **I want a random option to store the answer** but I don't know how to achieve it. A little help will be highly appreciated ???

Answer (score 0):

If you have the options as list of items, you can use `Collections.shuffle` to shuffle and then show them as radio buttons.

Comment: I am not displaying the options as a list of item. I am taking the input from the users in the form of normal buttons just like a trivia old school style. I was stuck only at the part how to shuffle the choice so that no same option is repeated again. But just dont know how to randomize them and thanks for the suggestion.